# FFmpeg stream wrong order with codec copy

Tags: video, ffmpeg, stream, streaming

I have an input stream with those characteristics:

```
Input #0, rtsp, from 'rtsp://#######':
  Metadata:
    title           : Media Presentation
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj420p(pc, bt470bg), 704x576 [SAR 1:1 DAR 11:9], 10 tbr, 90k tbn, 90k tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: aac, 16000 Hz, mono, fltp
```

I want the same output stream, so I applied the following command:

```
/crtmpServer/ffmpeg -i 'rtsp://#######' -vcodec copy -acodec copy 'http://127.0.0.1:1000/001Cam007_H.ffm'
```

But I get this result in output:

```
Output #0, ffm, to 'http://127.0.0.1:1000/001Cam007_H.ffm':
  Metadata:
    title           : Media Presentation
    creation_time   : now
    encoder         : Lavf56.4.101
    Stream #0:0: Audio: aac, 16000 Hz, mono
    Stream #0:1: Video: mjpeg, yuvj420p, 704x576 [SAR 1:1 DAR 11:9], q=2-31, 1000k tbn, 90k tbc
```

As you can see the stream order are inverted. Searching on google I find this options:

```
-map 0:v -map 0:a
```

But seems that doesn't work for me
Can someone help me?

Thanks

Comment: What FFmpeg version are you using?

Comment: I use latest version "ffmpeg version 2.6.2"